# What Navien error is this?

Tags: water-heater

My Navien tankless water heater is showing an error message (although it's still heating water). I'm not sure if this is error 45 or error 116.

[image: Photo of Navien error screen]

Comment: Do you have an instruction manual? Or have you checked their website?

Comment: At least provide a model number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without more information, but that remote display is showing "45E" for the error code and "116" or "1 1b" or "11 b" for the subcode.

I found that error 45E most likely means there is a problem with the mixing valve.

Possible ad heavy site: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/833964/Navien-Np-180.html?page=121#manual
Another site: https://www.tanklesshotwaterguide.ca/about/navien-error-codes-and-troubleshooting/

Both show 45E as a mixing valve problem, but don't go into much detail other than that.